# Renaming and indexing list of rules

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, rule

I have a list of rules that represents a list of parameters to be applied to a circuit model (Wolfram SystemModeler model):

```
sk = {
{R1 -> 10080., R2 -> 10080., C1 -> 1.*10^-7, C2 -> 9.8419*10^-8},
{R1 -> 10820., R2 -> 4984.51, R3 -> 10000., R4 -> 10000., C1 -> 1.*10^-7,
C2 -> 1.85417*10^-7},
{R1 -> 12600., R2 -> 12600., C1 -> 1.*10^-7, C2 -> 6.29882*10^-8},
{R1 -> 16420., R2 -> 16420., C1 -> 1.*10^-7, C2 -> 3.70897*10^-8},
{R1 -> 26120., R2 -> 26120., C1 -> 1.*10^-7, C2 -> 1.46573*10^-8},
{R1 -> 76600., R2 -> 1283.61, R3 -> 10000., R4 -> 10000., C1 -> 1.*10^-7, 
C2 -> 1.01704*10^-7}};
```

Before I can apply these values to the model parameters I have to rename them.  The list above consists of six lists - four lists of four rules and two lists of six rules. Those that have 4 rules should be named "sallenKeyUnityGain" and those that have 6 rules should be named "sallenKey". This is what I have so far:

```
Table[If[Length[sk[[i]]] > 4, cirname = "sallenKey", cirname = "sallenKeyUnityGain"];
(cirname <> ToString[i] <> "." <> ToString[sk[[i]][[All, 1]][[j]]]) -> sk[[i]][[All, 2]][[j]]
, {i, Length[sk]}, {j, Length[sk[[i]]]}]
```

And this is the output:

```
{{"sallenKeyUnityGain1.R1" -> 10080., "sallenKeyUnityGain1.R2" -> 10080., 
"sallenKeyUnityGain1.C1" -> 1.*10^-7, "sallenKeyUnityGain1.C2" -> 9.8419*10^-8},
{"sallenKey2.R1" -> 10820., "sallenKey2.R2" -> 4984.51, "sallenKey2.R3" -> 10000., 
"sallenKey2.R4" -> 10000., "sallenKey2.C1" -> 1.*10^-7,
"sallenKey2.C2" -> 1.85417*10^-7},
{"sallenKeyUnityGain3.R1" -> 12600., "sallenKeyUnityGain3.R2" -> 12600., 
"sallenKeyUnityGain3.C1" -> 1.*10^-7, "sallenKeyUnityGain3.C2" -> 6.29882*10^-8},
{"sallenKeyUnityGain4.R1" -> 16420., "sallenKeyUnityGain4.R2" -> 16420., 
"sallenKeyUnityGain4.C1" -> 1.*10^-7, "sallenKeyUnityGain4.C2" -> 3.70897*10^-8}, 
{"sallenKeyUnityGain5.R1" -> 26120., "sallenKeyUnityGain5.R2" -> 26120., 
"sallenKeyUnityGain5.C1" -> 1.*10^-7, "sallenKeyUnityGain5.C2" -> 1.46573*10^-8}, 
{"sallenKey6.R1" -> 76600., "sallenKey6.R2" -> 1283.61, "sallenKey6.R3" -> 10000., 
"sallenKey6.R4" -> 10000., "sallenKey6.C1" -> 1.*10^-7,
"sallenKey6.C2" -> 1.01704*10^-7}}
```

This would work fine if all were sallenKey or if all were sallenKeyUnityGain. However, I would like the output to look like this:

```
 {{"sallenKeyUnityGain1.R1" -> 10080., "sallenKeyUnityGain1.R2" -> 10080., 
"sallenKeyUnityGain1.C1" -> 1.*10^-7, "sallenKeyUnityGain1.C2" -> 9.8419*10^-8},
{"sallenKey1.R1" -> 10820., "sallenKey1.R2" -> 4984.51, "sallenKey1.R3" -> 10000., 
"sallenKey1.R4" -> 10000., "sallenKey1.C1" -> 1.*10^-7, 
"sallenKey1.C2" -> 1.85417*10^-7},
{"sallenKeyUnityGain2.R1" -> 12600., "sallenKeyUnityGain2.R2" -> 12600., 
"sallenKeyUnityGain2.C1" -> 1.*10^-7, "sallenKeyUnityGain2.C2" -> 6.29882*10^-8},
{"sallenKeyUnityGain3.R1" -> 16420., "sallenKeyUnityGain3.R2" -> 16420., 
"sallenKeyUnityGain3.C1" -> 1.*10^-7, "sallenKeyUnityGain3.C2" -> 3.70897*10^-8}, 
{"sallenKeyUnityGain4.R1" -> 26120., "sallenKeyUnityGain4.R2" -> 26120., 
"sallenKeyUnityGain4.C1" -> 1.*10^-7, "sallenKeyUnityGain4.C2" -> 1.46573*10^-8}, 
{"sallenKey2.R1" -> 76600., "sallenKey2.R2" -> 1283.61, "sallenKey2.R3" -> 10000., 
"sallenKey2.R4" -> 10000., "sallenKey2.C1" -> 1.*10^-7,
"sallenKey2.C2" -> 1.01704*10^-7}}
```

In other words, if I have 4 apples and 2 oranges, instead of having:
apple1, orange2, apple3, apple4, apple5, orange6, I would like:
apple1, orange1, apple2, apple3, apple4, orange2. How would I do this?
Thank you
Tatjana

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution :

```
myFormat[ruleList_, {type_, counter_}] := 
 MapAt[type <> ToString[counter] <> "." <> ToString[#] &, #, 1] & /@ ruleList

(* example : myFormat[{R1->1,R2->2}, {"sallenKey",5}] gives : *)
(*           {"sallenKey5.R1"->1, "sallenKey5.R2"->2}         *)


sallenKeyCounter = 0;
sallenKeyUnityGainCounter = 0;
res = myFormat[#, If[
     Length[#] <= 4,
     {"sallenKeyUnityGain", sallenKeyUnityGainCounter = sallenKeyUnityGainCounter + 1},
     {"sallenKey", sallenKeyCounter = sallenKeyCounter + 1}          
     ]] & /@ sk  ;
```

myFormat is a auxiliary formatting function which is applied to each list of rules completed with the type/number of the item.

```
res // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: It would be shorter to use e.g. `++sallenKeyCounter`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, andre. I implemented your solution using Mr.Wizard's suggestion for the counters. I have not  used Map, MapAt or pure functions before and your answer also helped me gain better understanding of those function.

Answer (score 3):

This version implements a pair of counters, `a` & `b`, while retaining much of the original code :-

```
a = b = 0;
Table[
 If[Length[sk[[i]]] > 4,

  cirname = "sallenKey";
  (cirname <> ToString[If[a + b != i, ++a, a]] <> "." <> 
     ToString[sk[[i]][[All, 1]][[j]]]) -> sk[[i]][[All, 2]][[j]],

  cirname = "sallenKeyUnityGain";
  (cirname <> ToString[If[a + b != i, ++b, b]] <> "." <> 
     ToString[sk[[i]][[All, 1]][[j]]]) -> sk[[i]][[All, 2]][[j]]

  ], {i, Length[sk]}, {j, Length[sk[[i]]]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version where the counting is done by structuring the data with `GatherBy` and using `MapIndexed`.

```
lengthToNames = {6 -> "sallenKey", 4 -> "sallenKeyUnityGain"};
gatheredSk = GatherBy[sk, Length];
positionToNames = MapIndexed[
   With[{basename = Length[#[[1]]] /. lengthToNames}, {First[#2], 
       index_, ___} :> basename <> ToString[index]] &, gatheredSk];
rewrite[rule_, name_] := ReplacePart[rule, 1 -> name <> "." <> ToString[First@rule]];

Flatten[
  MapIndexed[# /. rule_Rule :> rewrite[rule, #2 /. positionToNames] &, gatheredSk, {3}],
  1]
```

The key is to write a rule that maps positions in `gatheredSk` to base names.

```
positionToNames
```

> ```
> {{1, index$_, ___} :> "sallenKeyUnityGain" <> ToString[index$],
>  {2, index$_, ___} :> "sallenKey" <> ToString[index$]}
> ```

In this case, it's just as easy to do it by hand. :)  Except above the rule was constructed without assuming the order of elements in `sk`.  (Given the problem of getting the numbering right, we probably could have assumed length 4 will always be in position 1, etc.)